# Check if input is a integer

Tags: python

I am writing a program that will ask the user to enter in an integer, and if it is not an integer, i will print "Error" and exit the program.

I tried this:

```
userNumber = input()
try:
    val = int(userNumber)
except ValueError:
    print("Error")
    exit()
```

But this is not working and is giving me an error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what is the **full text** of the error?

Comment: You have a few `NameError`'s in your code.  `valueError` should be `ValueError` and `printf` should be `print`.  Also, your indentation is messed up.

Comment: OP must getting Indentation error,

Comment: Please don't change your code after the errors have been pointed out...

Comment: if i try entering the letter X i get the error:

line 7, in <module>
    userNumber = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: you using python 2x???

Comment: If I've answered your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it and you'll get plus 2 to your rep. Plus one for the effort.

Comment: I've removed the typos as this question is actually about input versus raw_input in Python2. I don't think this question should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Python 2 I think this is what you're looking for, and if you want a real print function (like Python 3 has), include this import at the top of your header:

```
from __future__ import print_function

userNumber = raw_input() # `input` in python 3, 
                         # the `input` function in '2' is actually processed as Python.
                         # equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt))
try:
    val = int(userNumber)
except ValueError:
    print("Error") # This is a print statement without the import in Python 2, 
                   # In which case the parentheses are ignored.
    exit()
```

In Python 2, `input` is [equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: raw_input() not rawinput()

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous problems with your program. The indentation is incorrect - the statements under `try` and `except` should be indented. Second, it's `ValueError`, not `valueError`. Third, you should be using `print()` instead of `printf()`. Finally, since you appear to be using Python 2, you should be using `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.